# stuff of legend

Tags: phrase-meaning

In Malcolm Gladwell's book ***blink***, he wrote: "He liked to play poker and golf and to drink and, most of all, to chase women; in fact, his sexual appetites were the **stuff of legend**. "

Could anyone explain this phrase "stuff of legend" means? Thanks!

Comment: It means legendary, so remarkable as to be celebrated in well-known stories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The stuff of legend" is a (much) more poetic way of saying "the material from which legends are made", as if legends were physical objects that were manufactured out of physical fabric.  The word "stuff" indeed originally referred to textile fabrics, according to [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stuff).

Comment: Prospero, in The Tempest, refers to "Such stuff as dreams are made on"; in The Maltese Falcon, Sam Spade calls the black bird "the stuff that dreams are made of." References to "stuff" abound in literature.